# React navigation swipe between routes that load the same component but with diffrent data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react navigation but I am trying to make a weather app. I want the user to be able to have multiple locations saved and by swiping to the right you switch to a different location. So the component stays the same but the data changes.

Does anyone know how I can this working? I am using StackNavigator at the moment but I don't see any docs about this. (The whole locations storing I already know how to do, so its only about the swipe navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who might want to get to the same point. I figured it out and I used a normal flatlist to display the different locations. I made the item full width and added these props to the flatlist component.

```
snapToAlignment={"start"}
decelerationRate={"fast"}
pagingEnabled
style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
```

This will make the item full width and height and it will snap when you swipe to left or right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Swipeable} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
 

const Left=()=>{
//call a funcion 
or 
return   // value after a call 
};

const Right =() => {
return (
  <View>
    <Icon
      name="trash-outline"
      size={ms(28)}
      color="black"
      onPress={() => {
        //call a function to change the data.
      }}
    />
  </View>
);


};

<Swipeable
            renderRightActions={() => Right()}
            renderLeftActions={() => Left()}>  
//your component here 
</Swipable>
```

you can swipe right and left over a component and directly call the function as user swipe or show a icon to call the function.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and see if this is the solution